# Linux is loading wrong drivers

Tags: linux, drivers

I have a lot of problems.
 Is there a way to fix some or all of this errors by the Kernel config (**make menuconfig**)?

Hardware: [Acer Aspire 3 (A315-41-R001)](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.GY9AA.004)

Operating system: KDE neon (Ubuntu 18.04)

Linux Kernel version: 4.20.12

**lscpu**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               17
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
Stepping:            0
CPU MHz:             1429.807
CPU max MHz:         2000,0000
CPU min MHz:         1600,0000
BogoMIPS:            3992.26
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx hw_pstate sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
```

The **AMD 8111 GPIO driver** is not get loaded.
There are a few 8111 driver which not get loaded like in this case:

```
        *** PC SMBus host controller drivers ***
< > ALI 1535
< > ALI 1563
< > ALI 15x3
< > AMD 756/766/768/8111 and nVidia nForce
< > AMD 8111
< > Intel 82801 (ICH/PCH)
< > Intel SCH SMBus 1.0
< > Intel iSMT SMBus Controller
<M> Intel PIIX4 and compatible (ATI/AMD/Serverworks/Broadcom/SMSC)
```

The original AMD 8111 driver is available but Linux is loading a Intel driver.

In Hardware Monitoring support also gets the wrong driver loaded, it loads the 10h+ driver but it is the 15h CPU

```
    -- Hardware Monitoring support --

< >   AMD Athlon64/FX or Opteron temperature sensor
<*>   AMD Family 10h+ temperature sensor
< >   AMD Family 15h processor power
```

**journalctl -xb**

```
linux kernel: [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
linux kernel: [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
linux kernel: [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping


linux kernel: do_IRQ: 4.55 No irq handler for vector
linux kernel:   #5
linux kernel: do_IRQ: 5.55 No irq handler for vector
linux kernel:   #6
linux kernel: do_IRQ: 6.55 No irq handler for vector
linux kernel:   #7
linux kernel: do_IRQ: 7.55 No irq handler for vector


linux kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q46], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181003/dswload2-316)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181003/psobject-221)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Method (20181003/psloop-543)
linux kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2.BCM5], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/dswload2-160)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20181003/psobject-221)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue table load (20181003/psobject-604)
linux kernel: ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Scope (20181003/psloop-543)


linux kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x8f7a5000-0x8f7a8fff]


linux kernel: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-129)


linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:   device [1022:15d3] error status/mask=00000080/00006000
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:    [ 7] BadDLLP


linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:   device [1022:15d3] error status/mask=00000040/00006000
linux kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.7:    [ 6] BadTLP


linux kernel: [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector ObjectID from Adapter Service for connector index:2! type 0 expected 3
linux kernel: [drm:construct [amdgpu]] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector ObjectID from Adapter Service for connector index:3! type 0 expected 3


-- Unit systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service has begun starting up.
linux systemd-backlight[645]: Failed to get backlight or LED device'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
linux systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
-- Subject: Unit boot-efi.mount has begun start-up


-- Unit boot-efi.mount has begun starting up.
linux systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
linux systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
linux systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service has failed


-- The start-up result is RESULT.
linux kernel: hid-generic 0003:1241:1503.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.4-2/input0
linux kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
linux kernel: input:   USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1241:1503.0005/input/input20
linux kernel: input:   USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1241:1503.0005/input/input21
linux kernel: hid-generic 0003:1241:1503.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.4-2/input1
linux kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
linux kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514ec flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc515a8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc51490 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc5149c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc515e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514b0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc514e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc51514 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc51540 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 11 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ebc0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ec68 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb50 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb5c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eca8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb70 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eb80 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4eba8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ebd4 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc4ec00 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 42 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48fec flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49000 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f9c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490a8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f90 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49140 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49100 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 29 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49180 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49240 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48fec flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49000 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f9c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490a8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc48f90 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc490e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49140 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49100 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 29 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49180 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc491e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49240 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc492c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49200 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49280 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc492e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49340 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc493c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc49300 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: acpi AMDI0010:01: Already enumerated
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 96 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f26c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f328 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f210 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f21c flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f368 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f230 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f240 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f268 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f294 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f2c0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: amd_iommu_report_page_fault: 86 callbacks suppressed
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f208 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f204 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3f280 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c940 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c9e8 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c8d0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c8dc flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3ca28 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c8f0 flags=0x0020]
linux kernel: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0000 address=0x00000000ffc3c900 flags=0x0020]
linux systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\UUID-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device: Job dev-disk-by\UUID-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device
linux systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\UUID-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\UUID-xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.device has failed


linux wpa_supplicant[827]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
linux wpa_supplicant[827]: dbus: Failed to construct signal


linux spice-vdagent[1258]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0


linux pulseaudio[1244]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono
```

Comment: I can't see what is wrong. `r8169` is the correct driver.

Comment: "lspci" i saying that the Ethernet device is a AMD 8111

Comment: lspci show it as `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)`. These adapters are handled by `r8169` module.

Comment: OK, what about the **PC SMBus host controller drivers** AMD 8111 is available in the Kernel but lit´s loading a Intel driver.

Comment: The question is too broad to answer about each piece of hardware. I suggest asking separate questions for that.

Comment: There is a common module for all PIIX4 compatible including AMD as you can also see.

Comment: I am not sure if that AMD8111 is needed, but anyway you didn't check it for your build.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Why don't you ask a new question with a real problem, but not "Linux is loading wrong drivers"?

Comment: [AMD 8111 is an Athlon processor chipset that was released around year 2003](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/013/AMD-8111-pdf.php) and so unlikely to be relevant with modern AMD Ryzen systems. The temperature sensor driver is for AMD processor family 10h **and above**, the power consumption sensor is for specific family 15h and 16h processor only (= processors designed for server use?), and your system does not seem to have the matching PCI device that the power driver would use.

Answer (score 1):

[This question on AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/q/805008/769591) had similar AMD IOMMU errors, and they were fixed by adding a kernel boot parameter `iommu=soft`.

However, that might be just a workaround: the real fix might require patches to the AMD IOMMU and/or `ath10k_pcie` WiFi drivers.

Comment: I already have the latest firmware.