# What would be causing the following BIOS errors and why?

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Deepin OS on my laptop for educational purposes (Dual boot with Windows 10) a few days later, once trying to boot into Deepin OS it showed me the following BIOS errors and it keeps being stuck there without successfuly booting (tries then goes back to the screen)

```
[   0.412006] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC10.GPP2.BCM5], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/dswload2-163)
[   0.4120241] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-221)
[   1.2338621] pc1 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
```

I wonder if there is anything I can do to fix this, or if reinstalling Deepin or any other distro like Ubuntu would be okay, my laptop's processor is AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443398/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/596192/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503726/117549

Comment: These similar questions show ACPI error messages are rarely fatal: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272357/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/ Are you sure your system hangs because of these errors?

Comment: Well, indeed the errors I get are similar to the ones here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596192/errors-when-booting-ubuntu-20-04-kernel-5-7-1, and it's the same laptop but with Deepin instead of Ubuntu, however for me what happens is Bios Errors > Deepin boot logo > Bios Errors (and the screen also goes blank unless I press any key if I leave it at the error screen for some time) so it never successfully boots, I had to turn it off and boot to windows instead.

Comment: If it wouldn't be considered risky to reinstall Deepin, or any other linux distro then I'm okay with that, especially if  it's not too hard to get rid of Deepin that is currently installed.